# Add value to GridView Control Column on button click residing outside the GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview

I am using a FileUpload Control on my web page. I select a File Name in that control. On a click of a button below my FileUpload control that File Name should be added to a GridView Control displayed on same page.
I have taken a GridView control for this with specifying columns. I want that FileName value in a certain column that I have specified.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: Use a collection as `DataSource`, for example a `DataTable` and add these file-names.

Comment: But I have already specified the columns in GridView, one column is a Template Field where I will bind the Drop-Down and in other column I need those File Names. The user can select as many files one by one in FileUpload Control.

Comment: can you show the code snippet of your datagrid and value binding?

Comment: Tim Schmelter - I was trying option suggested by you only. But I got confused since I predefined my grid column. Now doing the datatable way specifying column within datatable. Thanks.